# How to read the selected lines from a dataset with non-even intervals?

Tags: python, numpy

I've this text file which has an increasing order in second column, but at some points some values repeat itself e.g.,`0,12,12,36,..`. I'm referring to the rows which are separated by `0 0` and then `1 0` and so on. I just want to skip these, while reading the data. So the second column has the increasing value.

Can someone tell me any way to do that in python?

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 3 0.999551 0.998204 0.995963 2.02497e-06 8.08878e-06 1.81582e-05
0 6 0.999226 0.996908 0.993056 3.50103e-06 1.39702e-05 3.13067e-05
0 9 0.998916 0.995669 0.990283 4.90435e-06 1.95504e-05 4.3739e-05
0 12 0.998613 0.994464 0.987587 6.27845e-06 2.50041e-05 5.58512e-05
0 15 0.998309 0.993255 0.984888 7.63421e-06 3.03781e-05 6.77611e-05
0 18 0.998008 0.992055 0.982214 8.97082e-06 3.56643e-05 7.9433e-05
0 21 0.99771 0.990872 0.979581 1.03001e-05 4.09117e-05 9.09826e-05
0 24 0.997413 0.989692 0.976958 1.16094e-05 4.60742e-05 0.000102324
0 27 0.997111 0.988494 0.974298 1.29506e-05 5.13517e-05 0.000113877
0 30 0.996811 0.987306 0.971666 1.42973e-05 5.66363e-05 0.000125395
0 33 0.996514 0.986129 0.969062 1.56102e-05 6.17854e-05 0.000136606
0 36 0.99622 0.984966 0.96649 1.6868e-05 6.67128e-05 0.000147314
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 12 0.998615 0.994472 0.987606 1.24824e-05 4.97091e-05 0.000111026
1 24 0.997408 0.989674 0.976917 2.32538e-05 9.22819e-05 0.000204924
1 36 0.996216 0.98495 0.966456 3.37665e-05 0.000133547 0.000294894
1 48 0.995023 0.98024 0.956083 4.41221e-05 0.000173927 0.000381972
1 60 0.993849 0.975622 0.945978 5.45843e-05 0.000214354 0.000467853
1 72 0.992678 0.971031 0.93599 6.49638e-05 0.000254364 0.000552466
1 84 0.991501 0.966432 0.926044 7.5403e-05 0.000294247 0.000635589
1 96 0.990323 0.961846 0.916176 8.55362e-05 0.000332815 0.000715435
1 108 0.989133 0.95723 0.90631 9.602e-05 0.000372371 0.000796123
1 120 0.987925 0.952552 0.89635 0.000106095 0.000410211 0.000872709
1 132 0.986728 0.947946 0.886629 0.000116829 0.000449985 0.000951404
1 144 0.985536 0.943378 0.87706 0.000127786 0.000490311 0.00103029
1 156 0.984333 0.938787 0.867512 0.000138898 0.000531114 0.00110972
1 168 0.983124 0.93419 0.858003 0.000149945 0.000571148 0.00118605
2 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
2 60 0.993889 0.975779 0.946334 0.000122674 0.000481801 0.0010518
2 120 0.98802 0.95292 0.897129 0.000235474 0.000910013 0.0019347
2 180 0.981998 0.929939 0.849324 0.000360693 0.00136728 0.00281767
2 240 0.976087 0.907868 0.805034 0.00048759 0.00180865 0.0036021
2 300 0.970186 0.886203 0.762767 0.000606964 0.00221121 0.0042844
2 360 0.964519 0.865822 0.724262 0.000723555 0.00257783 0.0048463
2 420 0.959195 0.846993 0.689658 0.000830297 0.00290486 0.00533017
2 480 0.953931 0.828808 0.657473 0.000940967 0.00322907 0.00579317
2 540 0.948992 0.812283 0.629672 0.00105503 0.0035387 0.00617566
2 600 0.94387 0.795353 0.601452 0.00116622 0.00381699 0.00650445
2 660 0.938843 0.778862 0.57426 0.00126677 0.00406694 0.00680719
2 720 0.933909 0.762839 0.548423 0.0013606 0.0043114 0.00712883
2 780 0.929153 0.7477 0.525167 0.00145272 0.00455818 0.0074014
2 840 0.924413 0.732931 0.503387 0.00154657 0.00480149 0.00765192
2 900 0.919724 0.718536 0.482191 0.00163803 0.0050077 0.00783869
```

Comment: `0,12,12,36,..`? There is no such thing in the input records. Did you mean `0 1 1 1 0 0 0`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Sorry! I started the column index from `0`. What I meant is column `2`.

Comment: The second column have values from `0-36` and then `0-168`. I just want to ignore the values which repeating. In these two blocks values `0, 12, 24, 36` are repeated.

Comment: Ok. what about doing np.loadtxt and remove the column using a np.hstack of the left/right slices on each side of the column?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Can you please show me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the file with `np.loadtxt` and delete the second column with `np.delete` using the axis 1:

```py
arr = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
arr = np.delete(arr, 1, axis=1)
```

Comment: It deletes the second column, but what I want is to delete rows. For example first row and then 28, 29 , 47,48 and so on. The problem with `np.delete` is when the first row is deleted all rows are rearranged and it is not possible to index all these rows in the one call of `np.delete`. I guess I have to create multiple calls of `np.delete` in order to remove selected rows. Which is very annoying because there are 18-20 rows.

Comment: I am confused because there is only 44 lines so the line 47 does not exist and the current input does not contain any "47" field... Can you put an example of the actual expected output in the question to clarify this?